# Is Pull back of Lie group a Lie group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a submersion. Then, $M\times_NM$ is a smooth manifold from Transversal theorem.

> Suppose $\theta:G\rightarrow H$ is a morphism of Lie groups. Assume that it is a submersion. Does it imply $G\times_H G$ is a Lie group?

As $G\rightarrow H$ is submersion, $G\times_H G $ is a smooth manifold. Does it have to be Lie group?

When will $G\times_H G$ is a Lie group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it’s always a Lie group.

Closure under multiplication and inverses you can check, so it’s a group. For smoothness, note $M\times_NM$ isn’t just a manifold, but an embedded submanifold of $M\times M$. The multiplication and inversion for $G\times_HG$ are restricted from $G\times G$ to the submanifold, hence smooth.

Comment: Ok. Restriction of smooth map to embeded submanifold is smooth.. So, it i the case.. Thanks

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No problem!

Comment: I have added more details as a community wiki answer. Let me know if I am missing something. Thank you :)